# Excel display dates horizontally

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to develop an Agile sprint spreadsheet that takes into account the effort spent on each task on each day.

At the top of the sheet i have two fields, Start date and Sprint Duration.

What i want to achieve is underneath this, display the dates, starting at the first date and extending horizontally to the right.

Is this possible to achieve?

```
Today   7/19/2018
Duration    14
Start   7/19/2018
End 8/2/2018

Task            Estimated Effort    Actual Effort   7/19/2018   7/20/2018   7/21/2018   7/22/2018
Data Migration          10                5             2           3       
Design                  7                 7             3           4
Groups                  1                 7
```

Where the dates displayed are displayed dynamically as outlined in the question above

Comment: Please show an example of what you have and what you are trying to do.

Comment: is it possible to use tables in stack overflow? i have a rough version edited into the question

Comment: Sprint? Agile? Can you explain a little more background including an example of the data you're *starting with* and what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Using *Duration* in `B2` and *Start Date* in `B3` you could use these two formula:

The first date in cell `D6` (*7/19/2018*) is the *Start Date* and will always be visible, so a simple formula can grab that:
`=$B$3`

The rest of the dates needs to check if the previous date is less than the *Start Date* plus *Duration* days.  If it is then put the previous date plus 1 day, if not then leave the cell blank.  The formula is placed in cell `E6` and dragged across as far as you need.
`=IF(D$6<SUM($B$2:$B$3),D$6+1,"")`